# C++: Why does the same code run in Eclipse Neon produces different output in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, visual-studio-2013, macos-sierra

I've been writing programs for my C++ class this semester and I have run into the problem a few times where I will write some code in Eclipse on my Mac and it does not give me the results I expect, or won't work at all. However, when I run the same exact code in class on a Windows machine with Visual Studio 2013 it works exactly as expected. An example of this is our last lab. One of the things that we had to do required us to use `std::cout << '\b';`, but this would not happen when I run the program on my Mac.

`'\b'` will not work on my Mac:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
//Prints out header to console
cout << left << setw(20) << "Binary Number" << right << setw(20) << "Decimal Equivalent" << '\b' << endl;

return 0;
}
```

[image]

The code gives the same output without the backspace:

[image]

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Edit:

I edited this post to be more general with my example instead of specific to my project. This problem also came up for one of my classmates who was doing his C++ coding in XCode.

Comment: Are you relying on undefined behavior maybe?

Comment: What changes are you getting between the two? Sample code and outputs would help

Comment: @joe_Mclovin  Change the class!:)

Comment: @joe_Mclovin  MS VC++ has its own language extensions that sometimes contradict the C++ Standard.:) You should compile  your code disabling the language extensions of MS VC++.

Comment: These screen shots don't help much to diagnose the problem. You prove the symptom, that's nice.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Very possible that eclipse's console does not respect backspace.

Comment: Or does backspace just re-position the cursor? Have to write some hack code to see.

Comment: Thank you @πάνταῥεῖ. Is this a better example of the problem?

Comment: How a console handles the backspace is not up to C++. What I'm seeing in eclipse [with hacktest](http://ideone.com/Re7lsG) is "Hello<><><><><>Nuke!" Run from the command line I get "Hello" and the cursor flashing back at the beginning, not the end, and then seconds later, "Nuke!" MSVC behaves the same, but uses a windows console. Not interested enough to fire this up in a *nux VM and don't have a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eclipse console does not support handling backspace.

There is a long standing bug report for this (Eclipse bug [76936](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=76936)) At one point there was a fix but it was reverted as it caused problems. So the current state is that it still that it doesn't work.